# Do I need to install browser drivers to work with Selenium version higher than 4.6.0 in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

In one of the tutorials for Selenium I saw the following:
"Starting from version 4.6.0 (November 4, 2022) selenium comes with Selenium Manager packed in distribution.
Selenium Manager is a new tool that helps to get a working environment to run Selenium out of the box:

  -automatically discovers, downloads, and caches the drivers required by Selenium when these drivers are unavailable;
  -automatically discovers, downloads, and caches the browsers driven with Selenium (Chrome, Firefox, and Edge) when these browsers are not installed in the local system.

For example, to see the result of Selenium Manager work just run any selenium script without previous driver setup and explore ~/.cache/selenium.".
Does this mean that I don't need to install a browser driver in newer versions of selenium, but just run the script? If yes, then why such code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Causes the following exception:
"selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable"